# How to check if a thread is finished inside a OnClickListener

Tags: java, android

I have a OnClickListener, like this one:

```
  submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                if(connected) {

                         final ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Please Wait..", true);


                         new Thread() {
                              public void run() {

                                //DOES SOME CALCULATION INSIDE HERE

                              pd.dismiss();  

                            }
                          }.start();

                         showPriceDialog(price); 
                }
                else
                    Toast.makeText(this, "No Network!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();          
    });
```

How can I know that the thread is finished? I know that there is a function `isAlive()` that I can use if I construct my thread like this: `Thread t = new Thread(); t.isAlive();` But how can I know if my thread is still alive, the way I've constructed my code? I'am aware that this could be solved by using an AsyncTask.

Comment: usually I will define a class extends from Thread, and handler to pass data between this thread with other class.

Comment: What's the problem with using AsyncTask?

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure I follow what youre asking why not:

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        ...
    }
}
t.start();
```

Alternatively You could use the Activity's runOnUiThread() in the thread:

```
new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
              //set text here
           }
        });
    }
}
```

But to be honest with you both of these would not be any better than using an AsyncTask and I would highly recommend going that route.

**EDIT** Additionally you will not be able to dismiss a progress dialog from a separate thread.